# boost function and bind external symbol

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, boost, linker

I need to use bind and function in my program.But unfortunately vs2010 can't link my program.
I used following example from boost::bind documentation

```
#include <boost\bind.hpp>
#include <boost\function.hpp>
#include <functional>

class button
{
 public:

 boost::function<void()> onClick;
};


class player
{
 public:

  void play();
  void stop();
};

button playButton, stopButton;player thePlayer;

void connect()
{
playButton.onClick = boost::bind(&player::play, &thePlayer);
stopButton.onClick = boost::bind(&player::stop, &thePlayer);
}


void main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
connect();
}
```

> Error 1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall player::stop(void)" (?stop@player@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl connect(void)" (?connect@@YAXXZ)

i have tried the newest 32 and 64 verion of BoostPro and followed this tutorial http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5AmwIwedTCM.All but vs still produces same error...

VS2010 project setting include/lib path
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/47585151/vs.png

however when I turned on

> Linker->General->ShowProgress ->For Libraries Searched (/VERBOSE:Lib)

i noticed that VS is searching only for these libraries which are defined in

> Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies

http://pastebin.com/BCpEt8Zq

is it possible to check which .lib boost need for boost::bind and boost::function under vs2010?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem has nothing to do with any boost library (both are header-only). Try to simply *call* `start` and `stop` from within `connect` and you should get the same error. Read it carefully, it tells you what is missing.

Comment: I simply added body to the function  void play(){}; and it magically started to work.Can you explain why it is important and why it produces linking error?

Comment: @user: I think you need [a good book](http://tinyurl.com/so-cxxbooks) that explains that. What basically happens, when you do just `void play();` anywhere, is that you tell the compiler that a function named "play" exists *somewhere* in the final program, butyou don't know where yet. The linker's job is to find this function (an *unresolved external symbol*) and resolve all the references to it (like in `player::connect`) to that one function. You didn't have `play` implemented (*defined*) anywhere at all, so there was no way for the linker to resolve the references.